# How to split a string and update the dictionary in csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, strip

So I have a csv file with stock data inside it in the format:

Date,"Open","High","Low"

2012-11-14,660.66,662.18,123.4

I have successfully converted all the relevant data to the correct variable type, ie all Open values are floats, High are floats, date is string

This is my code so far:

```
    types = [ ("Date", str), ("Open",float), ("High", float),
      ("Low", float), ("Close", float), ("Volume", int), ("Adj Close", float) ]

    with open("googlePrices.csv") as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):  # read a row as {col1: val1, col2: val2..}
            row.update((key, conversion(row[key])) for key, conversion in types)
```

how to I strip every date value so that there are no '-' in the date values? And then convert them to integers? I tried to use datetime but I can't really understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating `-`s and converting the resulting strings to integers probably won't help you. You will absolutely want to use [DateTime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), more specifically strptime:

> classmethod datetime.**strptime**(date_string, format)
>
> Return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to
>   format. This is equivalent to datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string,
>   format)[0:6])). ValueError is raised if the date_string and format
>   can’t be parsed by time.strptime() or if it returns a value which
>   isn’t a time tuple. For a complete list of formatting directives, see
>   section strftime() and strptime() Behavior.

e.g.:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-11-14','%Y-%m-%d')
#datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 14, 0, 0)
```

Also, you seem to have a financial time series. There is no need to read the CSV and parse it manually. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) does exactly what you need very well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm new to python, what would the code be for this method??
       `row['Date'] = datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%y %m %d')`
and then do i update the dictionary again??

Comment: Since your format is `2012-11-14`, the mask (second argument in strptime) would be '%y-%m-%d'

Comment: My code is now:


`types = [ ("Date", str), ("Open",float), ("High", float),
          ("Low", float), ("Close", float), ("Volume", int), ("Adj Close", float)

with open("googlePrices.csv") as f:
    
for row in csv.DictReader(f):  # read a row as {col1: val1, col2: val2..}
        row.update((key, conversion(row[key])) for key, conversion in types)
        row['Date'] = time.strptime(row['Date'], '%y-%m-%d')
        print(row)`


and i get the error:
/

`ValueError: time data '2012-11-14' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'`

Comment: Should be `%Y` instead of `%y`. I edited my answer with an example of the code working.

Comment: Thank you so much!! How do I update the dictionary again so that the new dates are in it??

Answer (score 0):

since data are saved in a csv file, after read, they are just string, if the format of `Date` is fixed, then just simple remove the `-`.

```
types = [ ("Date", int), ("Open",float), ("High", float),
      ("Low", float), ("Close", float), ("Volume", int), ("Adj Close", float) ]

rowlist = []

with open("googlePrices.csv") as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        row['Date'] = row['Date'].replace('-','')
        try:
            row.update((key, conversion(row[key])) for key, conversion in types)
        except KeyError:
            continue 
        rowlist.append(row)
```

output:

```
>>> print rowlist
[{'Date': 20121114, 'High': 662.18, 'Open': 660.66, 'Low': 123.4}]
```

if you want convert `Date` to `timestamp`, use this:

```
>>>time.mktime(time.strptime('2012-11-14', '%Y-%m-%d'))
1352822400.0
```

Comment: If i do it this way, how would i compare dates?
I need to find the average cost per month, so how would I compare the dates so that I can read through the data and when the month changes stop and return the average? then move on to the next month?

Comment: if you want compare dates, you'd better not convert `Date` to int type,  saving row like  `{'Date': time.strptime('2012-11-14', '%Y-%m-%d')`, ...} and then your can do `a= [row['Open'] for row in rowlist if row['Date'].tm_year==2012 and row['Date'].tm_mon == 9 ]  sum(a)/len(a) ` to get `Open` average value on 2012-09.